# html css different pages linked to the same css stylesheet giving different looks

Tags: html, css

I tried applying the same stylesheet for a few different pages. I've pasted this code in my css file:

```
  body {
    background-image: url("../backgroundp.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top, center;
    background-color: black;
}
```

This gives me the image I want as my background on the position I want it. However, on 2 of my pages I'm using in html, that I am sure of I am linking to this stylesheet, the background is totally different. I am using this to link to the stylesheet on all of the html pages, in the `<head>` section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/thermostat.css">
```

I have honestly no idea why it is different on these pages. I'm fairly new to using html and css, so I don't really know how to solve this.

Edit: Here is the webpage I am talking about. I'm making the page for mobile use as well, which is why I included that part specifically, since that is where most of the trouble lies.
[The page with the wrong background layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG5YE.jpg)
[The page with the right background layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KQez.jpg)

Comment: It would be useful to have some pictures of what's wrong. There isn't nearly enough info in what you describe to accurately figure it out. Is there any other CSS? Is the structure of the pages the same? See [mcve] for more stuff

Comment: With the information you have given us so far, it _is_ practically unsolvable. Please go read [ask], and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: that is due to different heights in 2 application

Comment: how exactly can I make them all have the same height then? If I set the image to be always a specific size, then the pages still won't have the same background size, and I don't know how to fix that, or where that is even coming from

Comment: You simply want to set a min-height for body. Instead of juggling the problem using percentages for this purpose presents, you go with `100vh` these days. Or apply the background image to the `html` element to begin with, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Tha is most likely due to the fact that the pages have different heights, and how background-cover works. The property stretches the background proportionally, until it cover the whole width and height.

Setting the html and body tags height to 100% should provide you with the same results on all pages.